# how to loop over functions like mean() , max(), std() by putting them in a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a code that outputs the same results as the pandas' describe().

this is what I came up with:
[image]

I want to create a loop inside the dictionary values list to loop over the functions : mean, std, ...

Comment: Can you explain **why you're trying to manually reinvent pandas `df.describe()`** within pandas? Is this homework, a learning exercise, due to performance, curiosity or why? Otherwise, there's no need to rewrite it, and you can customize its percentiles with the `percentiles` list argument.

Comment: And if you want to filter the df to only do this on integer columns, first use `df.select_dtypes()`

Comment: Also, if you want to pass a list of arbitary or user-defined functions, [.aggregate()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) allows that: its `func` argument can be a single function/name, list or dict. So really I don't see any legit reason to need to reinvent this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to store the function in an array. Be sure not to call the functions => **NO** paranthesis.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

funcs = [np.mean, np.sum]
df = pd.DataFrame({"col": [4, 5]})

for func in funcs:
    print(df["col"].aggregate(func))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas to compute your values, **then** convert to dict:

```
# example input
# df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(5,5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))

# example with count/mean/std, add all the functions you need in the list
df.agg(['count', 'mean', 'std']).to_dict('list')
```

example:

```
{'A': [5.0, 0.5033497591814908, 0.25537079639738725],
 'B': [5.0, 0.4311195890311792, 0.238291507402266],
 'C': [5.0, 0.394948910648723, 0.2937879884789999],
 'D': [5.0, 0.5694092003851056, 0.2733118347996942],
 'E': [5.0, 0.6275597155186036, 0.17523941542284563]}
```

or [as pointed out by @smci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71495591/how-to-loop-over-functions-like-mean-max-std-by-putting-them-in-a-list/71495643#comment126366503_71495591), if you want to customize `describe`:

```
df.select_dtypes('number').describe(percentiles=[0.25,0.5,0.75]).to_dict('list')
```